# Auto Generate views and controllers from existing database

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, view, controller

I am new to Laravel, I wish to convert existing project having more than 250+ tables. what I need to know, is there any way to auto generate views and  controllers from existing database tables with relations. Because working on tables one by one will take reasonable time. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any official package for doing this. However, checkout this package here:

https://github.com/CrestApps/laravel-code-generator

> An intelligent code generator for Laravel framework that will save you
>   time! This awesome tool will help you generate resources like views,
>   controllers, routes, migrations, languages and/or form-requests

```
Create full resources using a single command with migration or from existing database.
Creates full resources for all of the existing tables in the database using one command.
```

Comment: Thanks sir. I believe this will solve my problem. i will try this and let you know the results.